# Software Foundations Basics Exercise - How do I access letter from grade?

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am working through [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#LateDays.grade_comparison) by myself and am trying the exercises, but I am stuck on the exercise for writing the function `grade_comparison`.

```
 Definition grade_comparison (g1 g2 : grade) : comparison
  (* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH ":= _your_definition_ ." *). Admitted.
```

The definition of the type `grade` is given by

```
Inductive grade : Type :=
  Grade (l:letter) (m:modifier).
```

and we are given a function `letter_comparison` which takes two letters and returns if they are equal, or if one is greater or less than the other.

I want to apply the `letter_comparison` function to the letter portion of the two given grades since the instructions say to "do case analysis on the result of a suitable call to `letter_comparison` to end up with just 3 possibilities."

However, I am not sure how to call `letter comparison` correctly.

I have tried treating `Grade` as a record type,

```
(letter_comparison (Grade A Plus).(l) (Grade C Plus).(l))
```

```
(letter_comparison (Grade A Plus).(letter) (Grade C Plus).(letter))
```

but nothing I have tried so far compiles.

I can write a separate function that returns the letter from a grade

```
Definition get_letter (g : grade) : letter :=
    match g with 
    | Grade A _ => A
    | Grade B _ => B
    | Grade C _ => C
    | Grade D _ => D
    | Grade F _ => F
    end.

Compute ((letter_comparison (get_letter (Grade C Plus)) (get_letter (Grade B Plus)))).
```

However, I think there is a way to do this without having to define this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't know of an alternative way to get the letter from the grade other than a simplified `get_letter`:

```
Definition get_letter (g : grade) :=
  match g with Grade x _ => x end.
```

I think this is more or less standard. For example, the `pair` type is defined similarly to `grade` and the way we obtain the first or second elements of the pair is through dedicated functions, `fst` and `snd` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I am struggling with this function as well, but Ana Borges's answer above demonstrated that you can parametrise constructors in the pattern-matching clause:

`match g with Grade x _ => x end.`

We can use this knowledge to solve the task without resorting to anything but pattern-matching:

```
Definition grade_comparison (g1 g2 : grade) : comparison :=
  match g1, g2 with
  | Grade l1 m1, Grade l2 m2 => 
    match (letter_comparison l1 l2) with
    | Eq => modifier_comparison m1 m2
    | not_eq => not_eq
    end 
  end.
```

This definition passes the examples right after the task just well. I still don't quite understand what "3 possibilities" mean though, so maybe this solution is not an intended one.

Comment: Pretty sure the 3 possibilities are `Eq`, `Lt` and `Gt`, but you've merged `Lt` and `Gt` in `not_eq`.

Comment: `not_eq` above can be either `Gt` or `Lt`. If it is eg `Gt`, then the result of the `grade_comparison` function is also `Gt`. Same for `Lt`.